# Automation of find replace in multiple xml files

Tags: xml, automation

I need to test a software enhancement I made recently.  To do this, I need to make 1000 changes in 56 xml loader files (so 56,000 total).  Specifically, I need to change the following:

```
   </users> 
</service>
```

into this

```
   </users>
   <rules>
       <ruleid="13e77ade-f15c-433f-aac8-2fdaf2d867a5" /> 
   </rules>
   <temprestriction /> 
</service>
```

I could do a find/replace on each of the 56 files, but that would be tedious.  Is there a good way to automate this process?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: there are lots of solutions for this. You could use xslt, pearl, powershell, php, Java, C#, ETL tools... you need to tell us what you want to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @ConradFrix mentioned in a comment: you can use different tools/methods to solve this problem.

Here is a solution based on XSLT. The code is not tested extensively.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="service/*[last()][self::users]">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        <rules>
            <rule id="13e77ade-f15c-433f-aac8-2fdaf2d867a5" />
        </rules>
        <temprestriction />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Key points: 1) using an identity template to recursively copy nodes of the document 2) a separate template to add new elements after `<users>` element if it is a last child of a `<service>` element.